# SQL while loop to find the next row based on name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, while-loop, case

I have an SQL trigger where whenever a new customer is checked in they are auto assigned to a technician. I have it working great with a case statement like this

```
SET @TechOrder = 
(
    CASE
        WHEN @LastTech = 'Tech1' THEN 'Tech2'
        WHEN @LastTech = 'Tech2' THEN 'Tech3'
        WHEN @LastTech = 'Tech3' THEN 'Tech4'
        WHEN @LastTech = 'Tech4' THEN 'Tech1'
        and so on...
        ELSE 'Tech1'
    END
)
```

Then it updates the inserted order with this

```
UPDATE WorkOrder
SET Technician = @TechOrder
WHERE ID = @OrderID
```

There is a lot of job roll changes and turn around for this position and I don't want to go in and manually change the SQL trigger every time there is a new tech. I was wondering if there is a better way to assign a tech based on the employee table WHERE Job_Roll equals this position.

I was thinking a loop or cursor may work to select the next tech in line, but am not sure how I would do this. I am using SQL 2008 R2 so the use of LAG/LEAD won't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about you create a table with the techs and the date of last assign workorder, then you select it from the max date and after you select it you update it with a new date.

Comment: Thats a pretty good idea, I'll look into that

Comment: If it solve your problem let me know, then I will post as an answer so it can help who else find your post.

Comment: will do, I'm trying it out right now, thanks

Comment: I got it to work,  The only hiccup is when a new employee is added and their assigned date is null so the max(date) doesn't see it. What I did was set a default constraint on the table to set a getdate() when employee is added. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Great I will post it as an answer and give some new things to think about. But it will be just new ideas that maybe come in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about you create a table with the techs and the date of last assign workorder as this: (the table and commands below is just the idea, don't follow the syntaxe)

```
techTable (
   id        autoincrement value,
   techName  varchar value,
   lastAssign datetime value DEFAULT now() --to the case you 
                                           --insert a new tech      
);
```

Then you select it from the **MIN** date (as it has to be the last guy that was working on an WorkOrder). I said max on the comments but it should be MIN given the order of work.

```
select top 1 id, techName, min(lastAssign)
  from techTable 
 group by id, techName;
```

And after that you select it, you update it with a new date.

```
update techTable set lastAssign = now() where id = idFromTheAboveQuery;
```

Then this tech will be at the last position for the next WorkOrder.

**To think about**

If you want to improve your project consider in thinking about:

**Do you want to have a history for the techs?** Put a field on the techTable to identify if a tech is active or inactive and on your select you filter it for the active techs.

**Do your techs work in shifts?** You can create a new table `shifts(id, starttime, endtime)` and put a FK on techTable or could be many to many relationship. That is up to you. Or just put the two more fields on the techTable (startWork and endWork) and on the select you filter `where now() between startWork and endWork`